# Adaptive Payments: Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment is restricted

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

We have integrated the chained payment successfully in our website.

Per testing, we have encountered the issue like

```
‘Account not found. Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment is restricted’.
```

Is there further instructions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is usually caused by receiver’s email address that is unconfirmed. Please ask the receiver to confirm the email and the issue should get fixed.

Here’s how to confirm the email address:
Log in to your PayPal account.
Click Profile near the top of the page.
Click Update beside Email.
Select the email address you want to confirm, click Confirm and we'll send you an email.
Click the link in the email to complete the confirmation process.

Answer (score 5):

A unilateral payment is a payment to an email address that does not yet belong to a PayPal account.

In most cases, the user would receive an email that they have been paid money and they need to create a PayPal account in order to receive/withdrawal the funds.

This feature is simply not available when using Chained Payments.  All receivers must have an existing PayPal already.

Comment: So, just to confirm, in the sandbox, a `pay` call that specifies a chained payment to a secondary receiver that doesn't have an account fails but in reality, the call will succeed?

Comment: No, it would happen live, too.  Unilateral payments are simply not allowed with chained payments like they are other types of payments.

Comment: We're also facing the same issue. In sandbox it works but in live throws error.